# styles for ngbmodal when using ShadowDom

Tags: angular

I have a app.component.ts with ViewEncapsulation.shadowDom. 
If the child component has ngbModal window which is appending to body(default) styles are not applying properly.

[ngbModal appending to body](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nobwwq-6hzu9l)

If I try to append this to a container throwing an JS error because of shadowDom
`Error: The specified modal container "#modalPlaceHolder" was not found in the DOM.`

[ngbModal appending trying to append to container](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nobwwq)

What could be wrong?

I Cannot append scss to head tag by referring styles in angluar.json

What will be the best way to handle this issue ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the shadow dom element of your id, first is you need to get your ShadowRoot which is `app-root`

```
document.getElementsByTagName('app-root')[0].shadowRoot.getElementById('modalPlaceHolder')
```

Should be like this

```
open(content) {
    this.modalService.open(content, {ariaLabelledBy: 'modal-basic-title', container: document.getElementsByTagName('app-root')[0].shadowRoot.getElementById('modalPlaceHolder')}).result.then((result) => {
      this.closeResult = `Closed with: ${result}`;
    }, (reason) => {
      this.closeResult = `Dismissed ${this.getDismissReason(reason)}`;
    });
  }
```